# How do you prevent short lambdas from being split between two lines?

Tags: c++, lambda, clang-format

I've got a clang-format question regarding C++ lambdas.  I've noticed new behavior with short, but not on-line lambdas after upgrading to Clang-Format 15.0.1.  I call them "Two-line lambdas" below.  Examples:

**One-line lambdas**

```
// good/unchanged
auto shortLambda= []() { doSomething(); };
```

**Two-line lambdas:**

```
// unwanted/new behavior
const auto mediumLambda = [some, args, here](More arguments)
{ return doSomething(some, args, here, arguments); };
```

**Multiline Lambdas:**

```
// good/unchanged
const auto longLambda= [some, args, here](Are here)
{
   auto result =doSomething(some, args, here, arguments); 
   return result;
};
```

**Desired behavior of Two-line lambdas:**

```
// desired
const auto mediumLambda = [some, args, here](More arguments)
{
   return doSomething(some, args, here, arguments); 
};
```

**Rational:** "two line" if statements are not smashed together on two lines

```
// Good/unchanged
if (condition)
{
   doWhatever();
}

// Bad/unconfigured:
if (condition)
{ doWhatever(); }
```

I can get all lambdas to be multiline ones by setting `AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine : None` - but I do want the ones that can fit on one line to fit on one line.

**How can I avoid 'two line lambdas?**

Relevant configurations:

```
# Basic
Language : Cpp
Standard : c++20
ColumnLimit : '110'

# Tabs
TabWidth : '3'
IndentWidth : '3'
UseTab : Never

# Braces/Parens (Allman style)
BreakBeforeBraces : Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  true
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  BeforeLambdaBody: true
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
Cpp11BracedListStyle : true
SpaceBeforeParens : ControlStatements
SpacesInParentheses  : false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses : false


# Functions
AlignAfterOpenBracket : Align
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine : false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine : Inline
BinPackArguments : true
BinPackParameters  : true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine : true
IndentWrappedFunctionNames : false
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType : None
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType : None

# Lambdas
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine : All
```

Edit: added semicolons to make valid C++.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that is not possible. If I were to guess, the tool first checks that you allow short lambdas, then notices that it won't fit in one line, so it applies `BraceWrapping: BeforeLambdaBody` and rests satisfied, because everything is within column limits now.

If you can sacrifice Allman's style in this case, `BraceWrapping: BeforeLambdaBody` set to `false` will result in

```
const auto mediumLambda = [some, args, here](More arguments) { 
    return doSomething(some, args, here, arguments); 
};
```

while keeping short lambdas on one line and breaking ending `};` if not possible to keep it in one line.

---

It may or may not be a bug, but it would certainly be worth filling a bug ticket to clang to either change this behaviour or improve documentation, explaining what the tool does in this particular case.

Comment: Thank you, @yksisarvinen.  I was afraid that was the answer.  I cannot (I guess would rather not) sacrifice the Allman style, otherwise what you suggested does work.